# Kernel of an algebra homomorphism.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra generated by the monomials $x^m, x^{m-1}y, x^{m-2}y^2,\cdots,y^m$ where $x$ and $y$ commutes. This implies the generators are not algebraically independent. So the algebra is not isomorphic to the polynomial algebra generated by these monomials. But it must be isomorphic to a quotient of the polynomial algebra $\mathbb{K}[x^m, x^{m-1}y, x^{m-2}y^2,\cdots,y^m]$.
Can anyone help me to find out the ideal by which I need to quotient the polynomial algebra. Obviously there are few relations that can be obtained but I am not getting any idea to specifically find out the ideal.

Comment: This is the homogeneous coordinate ring of the $m$-uple (or $m$'th veronese) embedding $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$. The ideal of these are well known, but I'll give you a hint to figure out this case: the ideal $I(X) \subset \mathbb{K}[y_0, \dots, y_m]$ will be generated by some well chosen quadratic forms $y_iy_j - y_ky_l$.

Comment: $A$ *is* $\mathbb{K}[x^m, x^{m-1}y, \dots,y^m],$ not a quotient of it.